# boost bfs predecessor_map issues

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I'm trying to learn how to use the Boost Graph Library, but I'm running into a few issues. As I understand it, the two calls to `boost::breadth_first_search` in the following code should be equivalent, but the `predecessor_map` version doesn't work (`p` is left unchanged).

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    typedef boost::adjacency_list<
        boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS> Graph;

    typedef Graph::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
    typedef std::pair<vertex_t, vertex_t> edge;

    edge edges[] = {
        edge(0, 1), edge(1, 2), edge(2, 3), edge(0, 4), edge(4, 5), edge(5, 6),
        edge(6, 7), edge(7, 8)
    };

    Graph g(edges, edges + sizeof(edges) / sizeof(edge), 9);
    std::cout << boost::num_vertices(g) << " vertices and " << boost::num_edges(g) << " edges" << std::endl;

    std::vector<vertex_t> p(boost::num_vertices(g)), d(boost::num_vertices(g));
    vertex_t s = *(boost::vertices(g).first);
    p[s] = s;

    boost::breadth_first_search(g, s, boost::predecessor_map(&p[0]));
    // this call works, but the above one doesn't
    //boost::breadth_first_search(g, s, boost::visitor(boost::make_bfs_visitor(boost::record_predecessors(&p[0], boost::on_tree_edge()))));

    for (auto itr = p.begin(); itr != p.end(); ++itr)
        std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
}
```

Could someone please explain the difference between these two calls? Why doesn't the named parameter version work? Also, I couldn't find an answer to this in the documentation, but can two different visitors (eg `predecessor_map` and a custom one) process the same event, eg `on_tree_edge()`?

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/breadth_first_search.html) it seems `predecessor_map` is not one of the possible named parameters you can use with bfs. I don't know enough to answer your second question with confidence but [this example](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/example/bfs.cpp) seems to use two visitors processing `on_tree_edge`. I personally think it's simpler to create a custom visitor that inherits from `default_bfs_visitor` and has whatever work the two different visitors would do in its `tree_edge` member function.

Comment: @cv_and_he Ah, you're absolutely right. I sort of just assumed that `predecessor_map` could be used with it seeing as it's a search. I feel a little blind because I didn't notice that in the documentation (which I did read). If you post that as an answer then I'll accept it, thanks.